# Getting error while using DataFactoryManagementClient.pipelines method

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to automate ADF pipeline runs from .NET. Was able to create a client and when I try to do the below call

`var pipeline = client.Pipelines.Get(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, "test_1");`
I am getting the error as *Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: 'The document could not be retrieved because it does not exist.*

Complete code below:

```
  // Authenticate and create a data factory management client
            IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(applicationId)
             .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID)
             .WithClientSecret(authenticationKey)
             .WithLegacyCacheCompatibility(false)
             .WithCacheOptions(CacheOptions.EnableSharedCacheOptions)
             .Build();

            AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "https://management.azure.com//.default" }).ExecuteAsync();
            ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
            DataFactoryManagementClient client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred)
            {
                SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Loos like it was a silly mistake. pipeline, I was trying to access from here was deleted by another process and hence this call failed.